# How to calculate the total salary from inside a for loop

Tags: python

I want to calculate the total number of pennies after the user has input a certain number of days and the for loop runs giving the amount of "pennies" after each iteration. I want to sum up all of the right sided column so that it gives a total in the format $xx.xx.

```
 numberOfDaysWorked = int(input ("Enter the amount of days worked: \n")) #Asking the user to enter the amount of days they have worked
 salary = 0.01 #setting the inital amount of pennies 
 total = 0.00
 print( "Day\tSalary\n---\t----" ) #printing out the titles for days and salary
 for currentDay in range(numberOfDaysWorked): 
      salary += 2 * salary # this is adding the amount of pennies earned that day to the total amount of pennies that will be used toward the total
      print (currentDay + 1, "\t", salary) #printing out the day (+1 to ensure progression from day1 to day2 to day3 etc. and then printing out the amount of pennies earned on that one day)


     print ("Total Pay: $", totalPay)
```

Comment: I'm confused, why do you need a for loop to calculate a salary?  Can't you just multiple the hourly wage * hours worked that week?  And who gets paid in pennies?

Comment: it's just an excerise that they are doing to show how for loops work when given user input. i'm just trying to add up the sum of the for loop

Answer (score 1):

The sum of your for loop is simply the variable `salary` after the for loop has finished. Check your math though. That 2 seems off.

**EDIT:**

Based on your commments, just make use of your variable `totalPay` in the for loop:

```py
num_days_worked = int(input("Enter the amount of days worked: \n")) 
salary = 0.01 
total_pay = 0.00
print( "Day\tSalary\n---\t----" )
for current_day in range(num_days_worked):
    salary += 2 * salary 
    print (current_day + 1, "\t", salary)
    total_pay += salary
```

Make sure to explain your questions better next time, there are a bunch of different results around here because of that!

Comment: it's not though because that's not taking into consideration all of the salary outputs before it.it's supposed to double the salary every day so that the output would be: day 1: 0.03 cents day 2: 0.09 cents day 3: 0.27 etc... and then at the end add all of those values up

Comment: Yes it is, you are using +=, you are increasing the amount in every loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very confusing. Do you mean that everyday, your daily salary increases by a factor of 3? Would this code provide the informations you require?

```
 numberOfDaysWorked = int(input ("Enter the amount of days worked: \n")) #Asking the user to enter the amount of days they have worked

salary = 0.01  # setting the inital amount of pennies
total = 0.00
print("Day\tSalary\n---\t----")  # printing out the titles for days and salary
for currentDay in range(numberOfDaysWorked):
    salary += 2 * salary
    total += salary  # this is adding the amount of pennies earned that day to the total amount of pennies that will be used toward the total
    print(currentDay + 1, "\t",
          salary)  # printing out the day (+1 to ensure progression from day1 to day2 to day3 etc. and then printing out the amount of pennies earned on that one day)

print("Total Pay: $", total)
```

#### Output for an input of 10:

```
Day Salary
--- ----
1    0.03
2    0.09
3    0.27
4    0.81
5    2.43
6    7.290000000000001
7    21.870000000000005
8    65.61000000000001
9    196.83000000000004
10   590.4900000000001
Total Pay: $ 885.7200000000003
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `total` and `salary` available. Add `salary` to `total` within the loop to get the "total" salary:

```
    ...
    print (currentDay + 1, "\t", salary)
    ## add these lines ...
    print ("Total Pay: $", salary)
    total += salary

print ("Total salary: $%.2f" % total)
```

Demo:

```
Enter the amount of days worked: 
4
Day Salary
--- ----
1    0.03
Total Pay: $ 0.03
2    0.09
Total Pay: $ 0.09
3    0.27
Total Pay: $ 0.27
4    0.81
Total Pay: $ 0.81
Total salary: $1.20   # equals 0.03 + 0.09 + 0.27 + 0.81
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is you were never adding anything to the "total" variable during the loop.

```
numberOfDaysWorked = int(input ("Enter the amount of days worked: \n"))
salary = 0.01 #setting the inital amount of pennies 
total = 0.00
print( "Day\tSalary\n---\t----" ) 
for currentDay in range(numberOfDaysWorked):
    salary += 2 * salary
    total += salary
    print (currentDay + 1, "\t", salary)
print ("Total Pay: $"+str(total))
```

Output:

```
Enter the amount of days worked: 
5
Day Salary
--- ----
1    0.03
2    0.09
3    0.27
4    0.81
5    2.43
Total Pay: $3.6300000000000003
```